# Proving Property of Certain Permutation Groups

Tags: permutations

I'm trying to show that there is no $g$ such that $g^{-1}(1,2,3)g
= (1,3)(5,7,8).$ I am having some general issues figuring out where to move
with this problem, since it seems difficult to figure out how to make a
contradictory statement to prove the lack of existence. If $g$ were to exist,
I know that in $g$, $5$ must map to $1,2,$ or $3$ because if it did not,
it would not be able to map to $7$ in $g^{-1}(1,2,3)g.$ However, I am having
problems figuring out where this leads to a contradictory implication
cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy if you know the following result.

> **Theorem**.  Cycle type is invariant under conjugation.

Here you have a $3$-cycle $(1\ 2\ 3)$, and so $g^{-1}(1\ 2\ 3)g$ must also be a $3$-cycle.  It can't be the product of a $3$-cycle and a $2$-cycle.